# This tag needs some re-[cnf]iguration

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I stumbled upon the [cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnf) tag today while looking for new tags to watch or questions to answer. It really was not what I was expecting which is why I'm here.

The tag excerpt reads the following:

> Common Navigator Framework - Eclipse platform provides this framework for tree based viewers

but the last question that would fit that description (as in being about the Common Navigator Framework even remotely) would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507660/filtering-contents-in-eclipse-common-navigator-framework-view), posted in November 2017.

These days it seems the tag is almost exclusively used by (what I assume to be, from personal experience) Computer science students to ask about [(Conjunctive) Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), with some exceptions I will list later.

## So what is the tag used for?

At the time of writing, this tag has 68 questions, of which:

- 17 are on topic for the Tag Excerpt (about Common Navigator Framework)
- 41 are about Conjunctive Normal Forms, SAT Solvers or connected topics
- 9 are about .cnf files (MySQL's [my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/my.cnf) is common here, but there are some others as well not related to MySQL)
- 1 I'm not sure about [(this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030808/deleting-ldap-record-with-0x0a-in-cn-java), I'd assume it to be on topic for the tag though?

### My proposed solution

I'm suggesting the tag to be removed in its current form as this ambiguity probably will continue with a [cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnf) tag around. Or synonymizing it to [conjunctive-normal-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conjunctive-normal-form). Input on this is welcome, I'm doing this for the first time.

So I will suggest:

Removing the [cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnf) tag, and retagging:

- Questions about my.cnf -> Existing [my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/my.cnf) where it isn't already applied
- Questions about .cnf-Files in general: Existing [configuration-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration-files)
- Questions about Eclipse Common Navigator Framework -> New [eclipse-common-navigator-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-common-navigator-framework)
- Questions about Conjunctive Normal Forms -> Existing [conjunctive-normal-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conjunctive-normal-form), adding [sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sat), [sat-solvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sat-solvers), and/or [boolean-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) where relevant

And, of course, closing and otherwise curating where necessary.

---

Some bonus points I found while researching:

- Closely related [dnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnf) had only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76003517/how-to-find-all-optimal-dnf-forms-in-discrete-maths) mistagged for the Disjunctive Normal Form which I took the liberty of editing out
- [sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sat) and [satisfiability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/satisfiability) probably need looking at, I can't imagine their distinctive tag excerpts to be followed but haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: "1 I'm not sure about". Pretty sure that's about [Common Name](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/common-name/).

Comment: *"Questions about .cnf-Files in general"* Is that even a consistent file format that could be a question topic?  Sounds like it's just [tag:configuration-files] to me.

Comment: *"Questions about Eclipse Common Navigator Framework -> New [common-navigator-framework]"* I'd go with [eclipse-common-navigator-framework] here.  It seems rarely used and I'd rather not see anyone get any ideas about what a topic with that many common words might mean.

Comment: *"Questions about Conjunctive Normal Forms -> Existing [conjunctive-normal-form], adding [sat] [sat-solvers]"* I'd specifically note that these should be adding those two additional tags _where relevant_.  It doesn't _immediately_ look like all of them are about SAT solvers.  Some look to just be about plain old [tag:boolean-algebra].

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've incorporated it into the question. Regarding sat/sat-solvers and the other tag changes for that matter, they should all be looked at independently and only get tags relevant to the questions of course.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a mention of [boolean-algebra] as well.

Comment: [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNF)